# SQL How to replace a value

Tags: c#, sql, dapper

I'm using a Database I was able to get all the data from the database and save it in a List<>. I made changes in the List<> using a DataGrid and now I want to replace each Database value for the List<> values WHERE the List.ID == Database ID. I use Dapper (In case it matters);

```
public void SetData(List<DatabaseInfoModel> database)
    {
        using (IDbConnection connection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Server=.\\SQLEXPRESS; Database=XXXX; User Id=XXXX; Password=password;"))
        {
            foreach(DatabaseInfoModel item in database)
            {
                connection.Execute($"UPDATE DataTable " +
                                   $"SET Name = {item.Name}, " +
                                   $"    Description = {item.Description}, " +
                                   $"    Record = {item.Record} " +
                                   $"    WHERE ID = {item.ID}");
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Off the cuff, your code looks correct. What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

you can pass a model, ex

.Execute("update mydogs  set age=@Age where id=@Id",dog);

"dog" is your model

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE DataTable
SET 
Name = REPLACE(Name, item.Name, 'Replacement Value')
.
.
WHERE ID = {item.ID}
```

Is this what you are looking for ?
In case you are looking for the syntax, here is more information:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15